# Idea, "Run Grails command" hangs after first attempt for a module after starting the IDE

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, grails

I'm running Idea 2022.2 on macOs 12.6, Grails 2.5.6.

I am about a week into using Idea, and I've never used Grails. I'm trying to build an existing project at my new employer, and I don't really know how anything is supposed to work. However, I have been making progress in getting my system properly set up. (I have a lot of Java experience outside of Idea, so I know basically how the tools are supposed to work.)

The project is an outer "umbrella" project with several sub-projects set up as modules in the outer project. One of those sub-projects has to be initialized with a Grails command, "package-plugin". I've been trying to sort out some issues with downloading dependencies, and I figured out yesterday that a key problem was setting up "unlimited" crypto in my JDK installation ("zulu8" for M1).

My issue is that if I want to go back to that module and do a "Run Grails command" to re-try, after the first attempt no further Grails commands will run; the Grails console just sits there doing nothing. The red skull does nothing. If I shut down Idea and restart, then the command does run again at startup, but once more it's not possible to do any more commands.

I don't have a clue how to even know what the IDE is doing. I presume there's some kind of background process maybe? that the IDE talks to, but that's mostly a guess. Are there some diagnostic steps to follow?

*edit* — I realize there's no code here; one of my problems is that I have no idea what artifact(s) in this pile of code pertain to the issue. It's kind of a desperation thing, in other words. If the Grails "Run Command" thing has no common "only runs once" behavior, then I accept that it must be something obscure about my own installation and/or the application I'm working on (or attempting to work on).

*update* — well here in 2023 I basically don't use Idea at all, preferring to launch the Grails build commands from a terminal. I think I'm the only developer on the team who does that but Idea was way more complicated and weird than what I'm used to. Thanks for all the helpful comments.

Comment: Are there any background tasks running in the bottom right corned of the IDE? Please provide a screenshot showing the console after reproducing the problem to better understand what happens with the IDE. You can try to capture 3-4 thread dumps of the IDE process via jstack to better understand what happens under the hood. (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899-Getting-a-thread-dump-when-IDE-hangs-and-doesn-t-respond)

Comment: Depending on the size of the module too,  you may need to tweak the JVM memory settings, that can have a big difference on startup / build times.   Re' logging,  check your grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file, look under "grails.project.dependency.resolution"  for the 'log' line and try changing that to debug or verbose and see if you start seeing some more output.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov thank you so much!  That's exactly the kind of information I was looking for, being a total Idea noob. I will try those things, and if I see something interesting in the UI I will add it to the question.

Comment: @DavidBrown as far as I can tell, once it gets stuck it's stuck. I *think* it involves a background companion task of some kind, because when I go to quit the IDE to try again I get a warning popup to that effect. I will do that logging thing also. Thank you very much!

Comment: (I do not actually get that warning popup all the time.)

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I get some info in the lower-right when the IDE is doing things like downloads or dependency analysis. When the Grails console stops showing any progress, however, there's nothing down there. I'll keep looking however.

Comment: @Pointy Check also if there are any exceptions in the IDE logs. (Help | Show log in... | open idea.log file | scroll till the end | reproduce the problem | check the diff in the logs) A couple of screenshots or a short screencast would help to better understand your case.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov yes thanks, I was happy to find the logs thanks to these comments. I went through the steps of getting the Grails thing to "hang", while doing a `tail -f` on the log file in a terminal window. I was hoping to get an exception, but I didn't see one; in fact there was nothing really interesting at all. I'm still working on it.

Comment: You can also contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for future assistance